# Safari browser not working for https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper for croped image upload using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, crop

I have issue with safari browser for cropped image upload using ajax upload.

I am using "fengyuanchen/cropper" library for cropping image.

I am using this https://cdn.rawgit.com/fengyuanchen/cropper/v2.1.0/dist/cropper.min.js

Make crop using this: `var example = new CropAvatar($("#crop-avatar"));`

And my ajaxcode on click save button like:

```
ajaxUpload: function () {
  var url = this.$avatarForm.attr('action'),
  data = new FormData(this.$avatarForm[0]),
  _this = this;

  $.ajax(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,

    beforeSend: function () {
      _this.submitStart();
    },

    success: function (data) {
      _this.submitDone(data);
    },

    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      _this.submitFail(textStatus || errorThrown);
    },

    complete: function () {
      _this.submitEnd();
    }
  });
},
```

In above code ajaxUpload function used for send all croped data using ajax and save crop image.

This issue only for safari browser and all other browser working well!

Help me for resolve this issue..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: First step, have you checked the console in the Safari browser?

Comment: @Xorifelse, yes i was checked with console, not any error displaying.